# How to inform a Flux that I have an item ready to publish?

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I am trying to make a class that would take incoming user events, process them and then pass the result to whoever subscribed to it:

```
class EventProcessor
{
    val flux: Flux<Result>

    fun onUserEvent1(e : Event)
    {
        val result = process(e)
        // Notify flux that I have a new result
    }

    fun onUserEvent2(e : Event)
    {
        val result = process(e)
        // Notify flux that I have a new result
    }

    fun process(e : Event): Result 
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Then the client code can subscribe to `EventProcessor::flux` and get notified each time a user event has been successfully processed.

However, I do not know how to do this. I tried to construct the `flux` with the `Flux::generate` function like this:

```
class EventProcessor
{
    private var sink: SynchronousSink<Result>? = null
    val flux: Flux<Result> = Flux.generate{ sink = it }

    fun onUserEvent1(e : Event)
    {
        val result = process(e)
        sink?.next(result)
    }

    fun onUserEvent2(e : Event)
    {
        val result = process(e)
        sink?.next(result)
    }

    ....
}
```

But this does not work, since I am supposed to immediately call `next` on the `SynchronousSink<Result>` passed to me in `Flux::generate`. I cannot store the `sink` as in the example:

> reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The generator didn't call any of the
>   SynchronousSink method

I was also thinking about the `Flux::merge` and `Flux::concat` methods, but these are static and they create a new `Flux`. I just want to push things into the existing flux, such that whoever holds it, gets notified.

Based on my limited understanding of the reactive types, this is supposed to be a common use case. Yet I find it very difficult to actually implement it. This brings me to a suspicion that I am missing something crucial or that I am using the library in an odd way, in which it was not intended to be used. If this is the case, any advice is warmly welcome.

Comment: is the `EventProcessor` a listener interface of some sort? Is it registered to a source? Or is it expected to be directly manipulated by the user to trigger a new data even manually?

Comment: @SimonBasle Yes, it is a listener. This example is a little contrived, in fact my class' `onUserEvent` are triggered by a `doOnSuccess` of a different `Flux`.

Comment: have you made sure your use case couldn't do entirely without the listener and sinks in this case? usually `map` and `flatMap` will get you a looooong way if your original source is already a `Publisher/Flux/Mono`...

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same. However, `flatMap` and `map` are used for serial processing. However I need to return the results from the original source immediately and then run a lengthy `EventProcessor` in the background. Also, the audience of the two publishers are different.